# How to change the DHCP configuration file in VMware player for Windows?

Tags: networking, windows-10, vmware, dhcp

With VMware workstation player, I use a Windows 10 host, and two Ubuntu VM-guests.

On my system I tried to connect VM clients, that get the IP address from the internal vm-dhcp and not from the host’s dhcp-router.

On Linux I could find and change the config-file, but on on Windows I didn't find the config-file. The solution was to download a gui-tool `vmnetconf.exe` and set the local DHCP there.

Why can I configure it thru the file on Linux and on Windows I need to download a tool?

Answer (score 3):

You can directly edit the configuration file on Windows too.

VMware's DHCP configuration file on Windows is located at `%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\vmnetdhcp.conf`. (The `ALLUSERSPROFILE` environment variable is typically `C:\ProgramData`.)

You will need to restart the VMware DHCP service after modifying the file.

Comment: May you give an example, on how to change the Configuration File for a Host only Network ? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

VMware communities had an anwser on that:

https://communities.vmware.com/message/1888335